# Branch IO sending empty response on init

Tags: android, branch

sometimes Branch returns empty json from its server on init. This is very random and for the same url branch response might or might not be empty.

```
  Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();
            branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitFinished(final JSONObject referringParams, final BranchError error) {
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            runningOnUIThread(referringParams, error);
                        }
                    });
                    Log.d("BRANCH IO",referringParams.toString());
                }
            }, a.getIntent().getData(), a);
```

referringParams: might be {} or correct data. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Hey @Kay, have you ever figured out what is the problem? I am having the same issue right now... Very annoying. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please let me know if you found an response to this. I have the same issue

Answer (score 2):

**Dev Environment :**

Turn the TestMode "true" to simulate fresh installs on dev environment.

```
<meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="true" />
```

Configure your iOS / Android app

Android : https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/ 
IOS : https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/ 
optional: 

 - Make sure you have configured branch io link settings in dashboard console properly. 
[image]


 - Get your params with proper key name which you have define in your params list in link management.

```
JSONObject sessionParams = Branch.getInstance().getLatestReferringParams();
sessionParams.has("paramName")
```

Start a Branch session :

```
    Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();
    // Branch init
    branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {

            if (error == null) {


                Log.e("BRANCH SDK", referringParams.toString());

                // latest
                JSONObject sessionParams = Branch.getInstance().getLatestReferringParams();
                Log.e("sessions params :", sessionParams.toString());

                // first
                JSONObject installParams = Branch.getInstance().getFirstReferringParams();
                Log.e("install params :", installParams.toString());

                processDeepLinkParams(sessionParams);


                if (getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getExtras().keySet() != null) {


                    deepLinkinData = getIntent().getExtras().getString("branch_data");
                }
                // Branch logging for debugging
               //  Branch.enableLogging();


            } else   {

                Log.i("BRANCH SDK", error.getMessage());

            }



        }
    }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
```